# How can I check if a React hook can be called without console errors?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, try-catch

Is there a way to check if a React hook can be called or not without having errors at console? If I do:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   try {
       useState();
   } catch {}
})
```

I get the following error anyway:

```
Warning: Do not call Hooks inside useEffect(...), useMemo(...), or other built-in Hooks. You can only call Hooks at the top level of your React function. For more information, see https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks
```

But I don't want to see these errors, I just want to know if a hook is callable. I know it's weird but believe me I'm going to use it in something much weirder.

Comment: Should work fine with `try..catch` https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-moore-8c88i9?file=/src/App.js:103-206

Comment: As mentioned in the warning: For more information, see https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you cannot call Hooks inside `useEffect` as it is illegal to do so in reactjs and may cause unintended behaviour, so you shouldn't do that.

If you want to know if your hook is available, you need to know that the imported hook, module,... imported correctly and exists.

So you just need to check if this module exist or not by doing something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   // useState hook or any other hook, module,...
   if (useState) {
     // then its callable
   }
 })
```

Another solution is to call it out of `useeffect` and check the result to see if it's called correctly or not, something like this:

```
const result = useState()
useEffect(() => {
   // check the hook result
   if (result) {
   }
 }, [result])
```